# System.TypeLoadException when running Maui.Graphics Live on Android

Tags: canvas, maui, drawable

I was running the app on Android fine until I added the curve functionality where I am using *Microsoft.Maui.Graphics* **IDrawable **with **GraphicsView** .

When I build the app on android I get this error

`System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 010001db from typeref (expected class 'Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Platform.GraphicsExtensions' in assembly 'Microsoft.Maui.Graphics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')'`

on MauiProgram.cs

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder //Exception starts here
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

**WeithPage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectAlpha.Drawables"
             x:Class="ProjectAlpha.WeithPage"
             Title="WeithPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:WeightDatesCurve x:Key="curve"></local:WeightDatesCurve>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        
          <GraphicsView Drawable="{StaticResource curve}"
                HeightRequest="{Binding HeightDevice}"
                WidthRequest="750" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**WeightDatesCurve.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;
using ProjectAlpha.Models;

namespace ProjectAlpha.Drawables
{
   
    public class WeightDatesCurve : IDrawable
    {
       static PictureModel[] picModels;
        public static DateTime[] dates;
        public static float[] weights;
        public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
        {
            //Assigning properties of the curve X and Y lines
            canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Blue;
            canvas.StrokeSize = 2;
            //Staring Point (0,0)
            Point StartPoint = new Point(20, dirtyRect.Height - 35);
            //End point of each axis
            Point EndX = new Point(dirtyRect.Width - 20, dirtyRect.Height - 35) ;
            Point EndY = new Point(20, 20);
            
            //Drawing X and Y lines
            canvas.DrawLine(StartPoint, EndX);
            canvas.DrawLine(StartPoint, EndY);
            
            //Scale values for both axes
            double xScale = (EndX.X - StartPoint.X) / dates.Length;
            double yScale = 5;
            //List of Points
            List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
            for (int i =0;i < dates.Length;i++)
            {
                double PointX = StartPoint.X + (i * xScale);
                double PointY = StartPoint.Y - (weights[i] * yScale);
                //Adding the current point to list
                points.Add(new Point(PointX, PointY)); 
                //Points to write the text (points)
                Point dateText = new Point(PointX, StartPoint.Y );
                Point weightText = new Point(PointX, PointY + 10);
                //Draw text
                canvas.DrawString(dates[i].ToString("M"), (float)dateText.X, (float)dateText.Y, 80,80, HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment.Top);
                canvas.DrawString(weights[i].ToString(), (float)weightText.X, (float)weightText.Y, 80,80, HorizontalAlignment.Left, VerticalAlignment.Top);
            }
            //Drawing the path (curve)
            PathF path= new PathF();
            path.MoveTo(points[0]);
            for (int i=1;i<points.Count;i++)
            {
                path.LineTo(points[i]);
            }
       //     path.Close();
            canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Green;
            canvas.DrawPath(path);
           // canvas.Scale(1, 5000);
        }
    }
}
```

**WeithPage.xaml.cs:
**

```
using ProjectAlpha.Models;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ProjectAlpha.Drawables;
namespace ProjectAlpha;

public partial class WeithPage : ContentPage
{

    public WeithPage(UserModel user, List<PictureModel> pictureList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WeightDatesCurve.dates = new DateTime[pictureList.Count];
        WeightDatesCurve.weights = new float[pictureList.Count];
        int i = 0;
        // var HeightDevice = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
        var HeightDevice = 500;
        HeightDevice = HeightDevice - (HeightDevice / 3);
        BindingContext = new
        {
            HeightDevice = HeightDevice
    };
        foreach (var picture in pictureList)
        {
           WeightDatesCurve.dates[i] = picture.picture_datetime;
           WeightDatesCurve.weights[i]=(float)picture.weight;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried removing the ScrollView, did not work, same error.

Also tried to remove *DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height* and also faced same error.

The thing is that when I run it on the windows emulator on VStudio it works perfectly but when building it, i get this weird error. I just hope it is not a library compatibility issue, I tried lots of libraries to draw this curve and only this one showed green flag.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I tried deleting target frameworks system version as mentioned in a microsoft GitHub bug report but did not work.

Comment: 1) Please provide link to that bug report. 2) What model phone, and what android api version? Emulator running same android version? 3) If no one has suggestion here, make new github maui issue. With public github repo. Maybe mention previous issue you found, if seems relevant.

Comment: this is the report https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14515

Comment: they closed it up as a mono debugger issue which i don't think is right in this case because even if i run the app on the phone without vs debugger it crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by upgrading to .net7.0 and upgrading Maui.Graphics to latest version as well.

Comment: Glad to see that you've solved it. You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it will be helpful for those people who are facing the same issue.